# How can I extract these values from json

Tags: json, sql-server

Given this json:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|a134a743-4f46942d175af9d6.",
    "errors": {
        "$.payment[0].invoiceDate": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]. Path: $.payment[0].invoiceDate | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 533."
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I extract `"$.payment[0].invoiceDate"` and `"The JSON value..."`  into variables?

Using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: My attempts fail at the first step.  Just doing
 SELECT  
  JSON_VALUE(value, '$.errors') AS exceptionID
 FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.errors') AS ex;

gives 
Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 18
JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '#' is found at position 2.

Comment: `select *,  json_value(value, '$[0]') from openjson(@json,'$.errors')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 3 different ways

```
declare @json           nvarchar(max)=N'{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|a134a743-4f46942d175af9d6.",
    "errors": {
        "$.payment[0].invoiceDate": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]. Path: $.payment[0].invoiceDate | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 533."
        ]
    }
}';

/* #1 without OPENJSON */
select json_value(@json, '$.errors."$.payment[0].invoiceDate"[0]') newCol;

/* #2 with OPENJSON and JSON_VALUE */
select json_value(value, '$[0]') newCol
from openjson(@json,'$.errors');

/* #3 with OPENJSON */
select value newCol
from openjson(@json,'$.errors."$.payment[0].invoiceDate"');
```

Output (each is the same)

```
newCol
The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]. Path: $.payment[0].invoiceDate | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 533.
```